# Hybrid Connection - on-premise SQL Server - SSAS

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have successfully connected an Azure Hosted MVC 5 web app to our on-premise SQL Server (OLPT DB) using an Azure Hybrid Connection on port 1433.

However, I cannot connect to our Analysis Engine SSAS database. I have enabled a firewall inbound rule on port 2383 but I can still not connect.

I can connect locally to the Database Engine, Analysis Engine and Report Server but I need to connect remotely as our web app is now cloud hosted on Azure.

So to simplify I need to be able to connect to an Analysis Engine (SSAS) database and Report Server (SSRS) remotely from Azure App Service using Hybrid Connection Manager.

I am using the following connection AdomdConnection (using dummy values for demo):

[AdomdConnection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjN3g.png)

I receive the following error:

[port 2383 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eib5U.png)

I have also tried using port 1433 but receive

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

The SQL Server VM is Windows Server 2016 and I SQL Server Browser is running under Local Service account.

Comment: I would suggest you enable an outbound rule on your port rather than the inbound rule.